# Python click consume options as arguments

Tags: python, arguments, python-click

I've been using `argparse` for quite a while now, but I'm transitioning to using `click`.

How can I tell `click` that an option-like argument should be consumed, without having to pass `--` on the command-line before that argument?

Example:

```
@cli.group()
@click.argument('script')
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def run(script, args):
  # ...
```

I want to be able to run this as:

```
mycli run foo.py arg1 --arg2
```

and have `--arg2` in the `args` list, instead of having to use the command-line as:

```
mycli run -- foo.py arg1 --arg2
```

Answer (score 5):

This is possible since Click 4.0.  You need to tell click to ignore the unknown option, and that you want the options gathered up and passed in.  Here is your example with the relevant changes made.

**Code:**

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--arg')
def cli(arg):
    click.echo('cli arg: %s' % arg)
    pass

@cli.command(context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
    help_option_names=[],
))
@click.argument('script')
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1, type=click.UNPROCESSED)
def run(script, args):
    click.echo('script: %s' % script)
    click.echo(args)
```

**Test:**

```
cli('--arg 3 run foo.py --arg 5 arg1 --arg2 --arg 4 --help'.split())
```

**Produces:**

```
cli arg: 3
script: foo.py
('--arg', '5', 'arg1', '--arg2', '"--arg', '4"', '--help')
```

([Source](http://pocoo-click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options))

Comment: Thanks! Not sure which doc is the newest documentation, here's a link to the page on [click.pocoo.org](http://click.pocoo.org/5/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options)

Comment: Latest is `6.7`: http://pocoo-click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog/

Comment: Unfortunately it only ignores unknown options. But I want to to ignore *all* arguments after the `script` argument. So for example if the script that I invoke from my command would accept a `--help` argument, it wouldn't reach the script because Click consumes it.

Comment: Is this only true for --help? It is a special case.  Or are there other examples?

Comment: It is also the case for other known options. In retroperspective, `click.UNPROCESSED` and `ignore_unknown_options` suggests this behaviour.

Comment: @NiklasR, I am unable to duplicate anything other than the problem with `--help`.  For that case I have updated my answer.  Can you edit the question to show the command line you are having trouble with?